# I am asking for a quick answer vs. I ask for a quick answer

Tags: grammaticality

What would be more appropriate in an informal letter/e-mail?

> I am asking for a quick answer.

or

> I ask for a quick answer.

Are these sentences correct?

Comment: Yes, your sentences are correct. A better way to say it? _Please answer as soon as you can._

Answer (score 1):

While both are grammatically correct, if your intention is to use the phrase as a concluding statement to a message *that conveys urgency*, you should prefer the present progressive tense:

> I am asking for a quick answer.

To be slightly more polite about your urgency (even in an informal email) you may also use 'requesting':

> I am requesting a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am asking for a quick answer (now).
>
> I (usually) ask for a quick answer (whenever I write an email).

Both are correct.

Comment: But if I write a letter or email and I ask for a quick reply. Would it be more appropriate to use the phrase: I ask for a quick answer. ? General sense. Or can I use both?

Comment: If you want your answer NOW, you should say "I am asking..." What is your understanding of "general sense"?

Comment: Hmmm. Now, I understand. The second phrase would be inappropriate (with Present Simple). I wanted to finish my email with on of these phrases and now I know which one I should use. General sense I meant that I'm simply waiting. I've read that Present Simple is used in general sense.

Comment: @masterkomp the simple present is not inappropriate or incorrect. the choice between the simple present and present progressive depends in part on the language and tenses used in the rest of your email.